# Can COM ports be used as RS232 serial ports?

Tags: serial-port, rs232, com-port, db9

Appologies if I am misusing/abusing specifications.

**Question:** Is it possible to send serial signals via the PC's COM port? Is it further possible to split this port somehow and send signals to two different devices?

**Motivation:** My end game is to accomplish the following

1. Generate serial signals such as "0101U" (see [here](http://www.automatedshadeinc.com/files/automation/control4_somfy_zigbee_pinout1.pdf), last page)
2. Send these signals from a linux computer through an RS232 cable
3. Send those signals from the RS232 cable to a CAT5 ethernet cable
4. Send those signals from the Cat5 ethernet cable to a Somfy URTSII interface device
5. Get Somfy URTSII interface device to control roller blinds.
6. Accomplish this for 2 Somfy URTSII devices

My initial thoughts were to control the Somfy URTSII device with a single Raspberry Pi, by purchasing an RS232 cable with a [built in level converter](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Pi-RS232-cable-Raspberry-Pi-Pi-Console-cable-/320953086488), and then a [DB9 to RJ45 connector](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200550CVF&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwordsCA&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwordsCA-_-pla-_-Modular+Adapters-_-N82E16812200550CVF&ef_id=UPMRmQAAVjAZoD6Z:20140301194130:s), and building two of these, one for each Somfy URTSII device. However, if I can control the devices (either one or both) from the PC's COM port, I will save about $35-$70.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_(hardware_interface)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PC serial COM ports are RS232 ports. I once once used a RS232 null modem between two of them to send files between two computers.